# Web 8.5 CMS - Rollback all items of selected publications to a specific date

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, powershell

Very Generic Case - In case of Application Release rollback, we must rollback all the cms items(components, pages, CT, PT, images, pdfs etc) of selected publications to specific date in past. Means discard all the versions created after date X.

Manually picking each cms item and doing rollback is not possible since its more than thousand items. Is there any quick way to achieve this, any poweshell command etc. Please share comments on same. Thanks

Comment: What does "Application Release" mean and how does this rollback work with the other systems in terms of publishing? For example, after the rollback, do you need to also publish the items? Is this some kind of "restore" in case recent changes are invalid and do you need to preserve history of changes after the specific date? Would a database restore work for your use case?

Comment: Hi Alvin - Web application is the one that consumes cms content. So if web application release needs to rollback then CMS changes also needs to rollback. Yes items has to be republished after rollback. Database restore is not the option because we do not want to rollback entire CMS only selected publications. CMS holds multiple applications content.

Comment: +1 to @Mark's point on bundles. You're considering "date" for the parameter to go back to, though there are multiple ways to identify related items for a given site. Consider localization status, publishing target, Bundles, or metadata to otherwise group items to a given web application "release." Especially for dynamic content, I've seen organizations use delivery-side queries to let authors manage content for different releases without having to only rely on CM-side history.

Answer (score 6):

As noted, you can script this. In fact anything you can do on the GUI can be scripted - and this is certainly a good candidate.

A couple of Points to note where you will need to consider a strategy:

- items that have been deleted may impact the ability to rollback items
- Items that have been unlocalised will not have any history
- items that have been localised will show the localised date - if this is in your capture range are you 100% sure if it should be rolled back?
- if items have been promoted or demoted

One strategy you could consider is to control releases within bundles - at least the scope of the effort can be contained for focus.

Comment: Yeah on bigger note I am looking for something in SDL to have Release Management Feature in CME. Thanks

Comment: There's a Release Manager extension knocking about but I think Bundles covers that almost. We did write a component-driven automated content porter for a client - anything you can do with Content Porter, you can do with the ImportExport API!

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no command to do bulk rollback but you can create your own tool using Coreservice (in powershell using core service if you prefer) that would find all versions of required objects created/updated after date X and then do a rollback.